# How do I organize a stacked barplot so the variables are stacked in a sequential order

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image: Three Variables Stacked]

I am trying to plot three different variables along the X-axis (date). However, when "Net Government" is positive, its bar appears on top of the other two variables. How do I change it so that the bar appears below the other two variables so it looks smoother with the negative values. Thank you.

My code looks like this:

```
netSaving<- melt(netSaving, id.vars = "DATE")
netSaving
ggplot(data = netSaving, aes(x = DATE, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Change the ordering of the `variable` factor. Also make sure your dates are actually read as dates!

Comment: Worked, thank you!